# How to check if all variables in array are set

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

First of all, I know this question already exists and already has answers, but I would like to stress in which way my question is different. I have code like this:

```
$ognjen=array();
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if($key!='prenos'&& $key!='submit'){
            if (strrpos($key, '1', -1)){
                if(!empty($_POST[$key])){
                    $uslov=true;//kontrolna promjenljiva
                }else{
                    $uslov=false;
                }
                if($uslov==true){
                    $ognjen[]=$value;
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['message']='You must fill out all fields';
                    unset($_SESSION['message']);
                }
            }//ovdje ide elseif
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't do what's expected.What I want to achieve is if all values of `$_POST` are set to put them in `$ognjen` array,if even one misses, none of them should become part of `$ognjen` array, but all that inside this `foreach` loop, because there are some other checkings that need to fulfill. And while searching for answers I couldn't find any that fits to my situation. Please help, I feel that this is pretty simple task to do, but I don't know way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function is_blank($data)
{
    $error_message="";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value=="" or $value==null)
        {
            $error_message.=$key.",";
        }
    }
    if($error_message!="")
    {
        $error_message=substr($error_message, 0,-1);
        return $error_message." is cannot be null or empty.";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

echo is_blank($_POST);
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I cannot use it the way I would like. If I do this:`$ognjen=array();
 function is_blank($data)
 {
  $error_message="";
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  {
   if (strrpos($key, '1', -1)) {
    if ($value == "" or $value == null) {
     $error_message .= $key . ",";
    }else{
     $ognjen[]=$value;
   }
  }
  if($error_message!="")
  {
   $error_message=substr($error_message, 0,-1);
   return $error_message." is cannot be null or empty.";
  }
  else
  {
   return "";
  }
 }
 }

 $prazno=is_blank($_POST);

 print_r($ognjen);
` It doesnt print values of `$_POST`

Comment: I cannot get you. you want to check $_POST?

Comment: Yes, `$_POST` is what I need to check.

Comment: I modified it a bit, and now it works perfectly. Thanks kind man :)